# How to do sliding window by value interval on non-time index in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to do a sliding window by value interval (window is: current value - value diff) but on a general value as an index as opposed to a proper time index.

The documentation of http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html says I need a time offset.

Is there a good way to use general values instead?

A test case could be

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1], index=[1,3,6,7,8])

sliding_window(s, 2, sum)  # expected result [1,2,1,2,3]
# for each element x sum all previous where index is in range x-2...x
```

I could implement this in (slow) Python with a couple of lines, but is there a way with Pandas?

Comment: Please provide some data and code.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to fill with 0's so that the index is complete.

In your example:

```
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1], index=[1,3,6,7,8])

s_filled = s.reindex(range(9), fill_value=0)

rolling_sum = s_filled.rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum() # your example does a rolling sum 3, not 2

rolling_sum.reindex(s.index) # Go back to original index
```